# Javascript window.open url automatically choose http or https

Tags: javascript

In my javascript application, my users can input an external link/URL somewhere in the admin panel. The users are not required to put `https://` in the URL field.

Just like how we put `somewebsite.com` in browser's URL bar and the browser automatically chooses `https` or `http` (whichever is available), the app should automatically choose `https://somewebsite.com` or `http://somewebsite.com`.

Currently, I have something like this in my app:

```
var url = 'www.csszengarden.com';  // input from user  
window.open('//'+url);
```

The problem here is it automatically resolves the website to HTTPS even though the website is on HTTP.

How can I open an URL (without HTTP or HTTPS) and then automatically choose whichever is available?

Comment: *whichever is available* Can you define this?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I think that op wants to detect if website has https enabled and if so then url should redirect to https

Comment: _“just like how we put `somewebsite.com` in browser's URL bar and the browser automatically chooses https or https, whichever is available”_ - it doesn’t, you have a wrong idea of how this works. The browser will make an HTTP request first, and then the server might redirect it to request the HTTPS version instead. (If the browser requested this domain before, and an HSTS header was issued, then it will use HTTPS automatically next time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this when you don't know which protocol the site supports is to use `http` and let the site redirect to `https`.

But if the user does provide a protocol, you want to keep that.

So a simple solution could be:

```
if( url.indexOf('//') < 0 ) {
    url = 'http://' + url;
}
```

You can probably improve on that, but it may get you started.